# Tkinter - scale all components on resize?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

Is it possible that when a Tkinter window is made bigger or larger, everyhting in the window is scaled?

So all the proportions stay the same but their sizes vary.

Now when the window is resized all the buttons etc stay the same so I disabled resize because there is no point, it just looks bad.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is likely not possible, depending on what you mean by "everything" and what you mean by "scaled". Any widget can be made to stretch to fill its allotted space. Text widgets and canvas widgets, for example, scale nicely. A button or label will fill the space it's in, but the text inside the widget won't change (that is also true of text and canvas widgets).

It's possible to organize your GUI so that when the window resizes, everything remains in its proper place at its original size. Having buttons that automatically scale is not something most people would expect. Disabling resizing usually results in a poor user experience -- users should have the ability to make a window larger or smaller.